# sprintf padding with non English symbols

Tags: r, printf, cyrillic

I encountered a strange `sprintf()` behaviour with the non English symbols. I tried padding a strings but I got an unexpected results:

```
lapply(c("ZZZ", "ZZZZZZ", "ЯЯЯ", "ЯЯЯЯЯЯ"),
       function(x) sprintf("%-20s: %s", x, "VALUE"))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "ZZZ                 : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "ZZZZZZ              : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "ЯЯЯ              : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "ЯЯЯЯЯЯ        : VALUE"
#>
```

Anybody can explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Session info may be useful:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Arch Linux

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C              
[5] LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=ru_RU.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] shiny_0.12.2      R6_2.1.1          rsconnect_0.4.1.4 htmltools_0.2.6   tools_3.2.2       Rcpp_0.12.2       digest_0.6.8     
[8] xtable_1.8-0      httpuv_1.3.3      mime_0.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you why it's happening, but not how to fix it. From the [docs for `sprintf`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/sprintf):

> Field widths and precisions of `%s` conversions are interpreted as bytes, not characters, as described in the C standard.

In UTF-8 the character `Я` is two bytes (0xD0 0xAF), so `"ЯЯЯ"` is 6 bytes whereas `"ZZZ"` is 3 bytes, and `sprintf` renders them accordingly.

#### Edit

One workaround is to use `sprintf`'s asterisk feature, which lets you declare the width of a field (in bytes), along with the [`nchar`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/nchar) function, which lets you calculate both the display width and the number of bytes in a string.

So, for example, `nchar("ЯЯЯ", "width")` and `nchar("ЯЯЯ", "bytes")` return 3 and 6, respectively. If we want to pad its width to 20 display characters, then we have to give `sprintf` a width of *23* bytes: 20 plus the number of bytes minus the display width.

```
sprintf("%-*s", 23, "ЯЯЯ")
#> [1] "ЯЯЯ                 "
```

Or:

```
str <- "ЯЯЯ"
pad.len <- 20 + nchar(str, "bytes") + nchar(str, "width")
sprintf("%-*s", pad.len, str)
#> [1] "ЯЯЯ                 "
```

This works for `"ZZZ"`, too, because the bytes and display width are equal, so it comes out to 20:

```
pad <- function(str) {
  pad.len <- 20 + nchar(str, "bytes") - nchar(str, "width")
  return(sprintf("%-*s: %s", pad.len, str, "VALUE"))
}

print(lapply(c("ZZZ", "ZZZZZZ", "ЯЯЯ", "ЯЯЯЯЯЯ"), pad))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "ZZZ                 : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "ZZZZZZ              : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "ЯЯЯ                 : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "ЯЯЯЯЯЯ              : VALUE"
```

P.S. This is the first R code I've ever written so if you see any ways to improve it please feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution with `stri_pad_right()` function from `stringi` package:

```
lapply(c("ZZZ", "ZZZZZZ", "ЯЯЯ", "ЯЯЯЯЯЯ"),
       function(x) paste0(stringi::stri_pad_right(x, 20), ": VALUE"))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "ZZZ                 : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "ZZZZZZ              : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "ЯЯЯ                 : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "ЯЯЯЯЯЯ              : VALUE"
#>
```

#### Update

Another solution based on the @Jordan answer uses only base R functions:

```
str_pad <- function(str, width = floor(0.9 * getOption("width")),
                    side = c("left", "both", "right")) {
    side <- match.arg(side)
    asc <- iconv(str, "latin1", "ASCII")
    ind <- is.na(asc) | asc != str
    if (any(ind)) 
        width <- width + nchar(str, "bytes") - nchar(str, "width")
    switch(side, left = sprintf("%-*s", width, str),
           right = sprintf("%*s", width, str),
           both = sprintf("%-*s", width, sprintf("%*s", floor(width/2), str)))
}
lapply(c("ZZZ", "ZZZZZZ", "ЯЯЯ", "ЯЯЯЯЯЯ"),
       function(x) paste0(str_pad(x, 20), ": VALUE"))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "ZZZ                 : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "ZZZZZZ              : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "ЯЯЯ                 : VALUE"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "ЯЯЯЯЯЯ              : VALUE"
#>
```